# Missing (obvious) buttons for Git in Netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans, configuration, netbeans-7

As I can see, newest stable version (`NetBeans IDE 7.3 (Build 201302132200)`) offers only four toolbar buttons for Git. Operations (obvious and most often used?) like `Push` or `Pull` are currently only available via clicking-away your path through `Team > Git > Remote > Push` menu:

[image]

Am I the only one thinking that this is strange and very uncomfortable?

Is this some kind of bug / missing, planned to be fixed soon or this is some kind of Netbeans' developers way of thinking -- i.e. it was set, that this should be like that, and no one is going to fix that?

I'm asking, because I was not using Netbeans from quite a time, but as I recall, there were many this-kind of *strange* things in Netbeans in its past, with devs' note: "*we think this is OK and we're not going to fix / change it*".

**UPDATE**: Actually, it turns out, that in some installations of Netbeans, you can add additional items, but these are represented without icons and remains as text-only buttons on toolbars.

Answer (score 2):

I agree completely @treider.

I can't even work out how to get the Git toolbar to display :S I'm using ubuntu and Netbeans PHP 7.3.1

Comment: You can't. You have to create new, custom toolbar (right-click toolbar, then `Customize > New Toolbar`) and drag & drop items from `Git` branch. Also, see my update to original question.

Answer (score 2):

See https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=233582 
It will be fixed in NetBeans 7.4

Comment: If you compare nicks here and there (`trejder`) you may come to the conclusion, that enhance mentioned by you was actually reported by... **me**! :] So, yes, I'm aware of these facts! But, thanks for keeping eye on and reporting here! :]